# How to change SSRS default multi-value parameter

Tags: sql-server, parameters, ssrs-2012

I have a multi-value parameter for States that is populated by a string passed from SQL.  The default in SSRS is for the State parameter to look like this:
AL, AR, AZ, CA...

Is there a way to change this so that the default shows just one value, such as "All" instead of listing the entire string?  I was able to do this years ago when our SSRS system was built on a .NET framework, but I don't see how to do this straight out of SSRS.

Thanks.

Comment: if you have set the default value of the parameter to "No default value" then it will show <Select a Value>

Answer (score 0):

I did this before but you kind of have to play tricks. I cant remember the exact syntax but hopefully this can get you started.

First I had to add an option of all to the datasource query

```
Select State From StateList
Union
Select "All"
```

Then there was something that I did to make sure that the all check box was mutually exclusive to checking individual entries.  Also it would only work if the All option was checked not if all states were individually checked.

Then in the report query change

```
Where State In (@StateParam)
```

To

```
Where (@StateParam = 'ALL') Or State In (@StateParam)
```

I hope this helps.  If someone knows an easier or more straightforward way I would love to know how.

Comment: If you are using BIDS then in parameter properties go to default values tab select specify value then you will require to add 'ALL' as your default value.

Comment: "Where (@StateParam = 'ALL') Or State In (@StateParam)"--this is how I used to do it years ago.  I'd forgotten about this.